# CakePHP 4 RequestAuthorizationMiddleware - how to dynamically redirect unauthorized users

Tags: cakephp, authorization, unauthorized, cakephp-4.x

I have implemented the new Authentication, Authorization and RequestAuthorization middlewares in CakePHP 4.0. I would like to redirect the unauthorized requests (from the authenticated users) to various pages depending on several conditions like their role, status etc. Currently, all the unauthorized requests are redirected to my unauthorized redirect url - Pages/Permission page. Is there a way to dynamically change the unauthorized redirect url from the RequestPolicy/canAccess function?

My RequestPolicy/canAccess function look like this(Edited):

```
public function canAccess($identity, ServerRequest $request)
{
    $unauthenticatedActions = $request->getAttribute('authentication')->getConfig('unauthenticatedActions');
    if (in_array($request->getParam('action'), $unauthenticatedActions, true)) { 
        return true;
    }
    else if(!empty($identity)){
        //check based on actions and user roles

        $userRole = $identity->role;
        $userStatus = $identity->status;
        $accountType = $identity->accountsubType;
        $action = $request->getParam('action');
        $controller = $request->getParam('controller');

        switch ($controller) {

            case 'Pages':
                return true;
                break;

            case 'Users':
                    if($userRole === 'ADMIN' && $userStatus === 'ACTIVE'){
                        return true;
                    }elseif($action === 'aaa'){
                        if($userRole === 'xxx' && $userStatus === 'ACTIVE'){
                            return true;
                        }
                        elseif($userRole === 'xxx' && $userStatus === 'EXPIRED'){
                            //redirect to custom 'suspended access' page
                            return false;
                        }
                        elseif($userRole === 'yyy' && $accountType === 'c'){
                            //redirect to custom 'restricted access' page 
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    ...
                    return false;
            case: "Sales":   
            ...
            default:
                //none of the Controller names matches
                return false; //redirects to the default unauthorized redirect url (pages/permission)
                //here if I return true, I get the MissingControllerException, MissingActionException etc as expected
    }else{
        //force them back to the login page
        $request =  $request
                    ->withParam('controller', 'users')
                    ->withParam('action', 'login');
        return true; 
    }
}
```

src/Application/middleware()

```
$middlewareQueue
            ....
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this))
            ->add(new AuthorizationMiddleware($this, [
                    'requireAuthorizationCheck' => true,
                    'unauthorizedHandler' => [
                        'className' => 'CustomRedirect',
                        'url' => '/pages/permission',
                        'exceptions' => [
                            'MissingIdentityException' => 'Authorization\Exception\MissingIdentityException',
                            'ForbiddenException' => 'Authorization\Exception\ForbiddenException'
                        ],
                    ],
                ]))
            ->add(new RequestAuthorizationMiddleware());
```

Comment: If this from your actual code, then you need to fix those comparisons. Use strict equality whenever applicable, eg `===`. Also a single `=` isn't a comparison at all, it's an assignment!

Comment: @ndm, thanks for your feedback. I have updated my post. It is not the original code. was trying to give an idea of what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No, a Policy cannot do that, that's not its concern, all it is supposed to do, is to answer the question whether the given identity is allowed to access the given resource.

If you want custom redirects, then you should look into implementing a custom "unauthorized handler", where you can check the identity and figure the redirect URL. For example extend the built-in redirect handler, and overwrite its URL generation method, something along the lines of this:

```php
// in src/Middleware/UnauthorizedHandler/IdentityRedirectHandler.php

namespace App\Middleware\UnauthorizedHandler;

use Authorization\Middleware\UnauthorizedHandler\RedirectHandler;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class IdentityRedirectHandler extends RedirectHandler
{
    protected function getUrl(ServerRequestInterface $request, array $options): string
    {
        $identity = $request->getAttribute('identity');
        
        $role = $identity->get('role');
        $status = $identity->get('status');
        
        if ($role === 'xxx' && $status === 'b') {
            $url = '/suspended';
        } elseif ($role === 'yyy' && $status === 'c') {
            $url = '/restricted';
        } else {
            // default URL from middleware config
            $url = $options['url'];
        }

        $options['url'] = $url;
        
        return parent::getUrl($request, $options);
    }
}
```

```
// in src/Applicatiom.php

new AuthorizationMiddleware($this, [
    'unauthorizedHandler' => [
        'className' => 'IdentityRedirect',
        'url' => '/default-redirect-url',
        // ...
    ],
])
```

See also

- **[Authorization Cookbook > Authorization Middleware > Handling Unauthorized Requests](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/middleware.html#handling-unauthorized-requests)**
- **[Authorization Cookbook > Authorization Middleware > How to create a custom UnauthorizedHandler](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/middleware.html#how-to-create-a-custom-unauthorizedhandler)**

Comment: I got the custom redirect working by integrating your suggestion. However, now the MissingControllerException and MissingActionException is also redirecting to the default unauthorised redirect url (/pages/permission) instead of the error400 page. Could you please guide me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @EssEss You would have to provide a way to reproduce the problem, as I cannot tell how that would happen, since by default the redirect handler only processes `\Authorization\Exception\MissingIdentityException`.

Comment: I have a switch function inside my canAccess method as each controller actions need to be restricted based on user role and some other factors. If the requested controller name not match any cases, I return false in the default section (please see the edited code in my original post). I realised if the requested controller not found, also go to unauthorized redirect when I return false. If I return true in the default section, I get the MissingControllerException etc as expected. Should I always return true if the request is not in my unauthorised conditions? Is it safe to do so? Thanks